# Transferring simple objects between Python and Groovy

Tags: java, python, groovy, python-3.x, python-2.7

It's possible to transfer objects between two Python processes using serialization/deserialization (pickle/marshal/shelve), and the same thing is possible between Groovy/Java processes.

Most simple Python and Groovy data structures like lists, dictionaries, strings, integers, even file-objects could be somehow serialized in a common serialization format, and transferred from Python to Groovy processes and vice versa.

My question: is there any Groovy module that could interpret Python pickled object streams and recreate simple data-structures in Groovy, or any Python module that could interpret Groovy serialized object streams?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there libraries for reading "opposite side" format (but maybe I'm wrong), especially if you are going to (de)serialise complex language-specific objects like files.

I'd suggest looking some good established cross-language solution like [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or simplify communication protocol and use something simple like JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go with Google Protocol Buffers, as it is very widely used now a days in industries.

Even, i used the same for communication between Perl serialized object and Java object and vice versa.

[ProtoBuf RPC example](https://github.com/orbekk/protobuf-simple-rpc/tree/master/src)

[Protocol Buffers Java Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial)